# Getting the name of the assigned variable to an argument in a function

Tags: r, function, variables

I'd like to state the variable that has been assigned to an argument in a function. Function is more complex, but an example scenario is below, where I want the function to return the name of the variable: `x`

e.g.

```
x <- 3
my_function <- function(arg1) {print(arg1)}
```

where: `my_function(x)` will return `x`

and: `my_function(y)` will return `y`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substitute` to return a `symbol` object.  If we wrap with `deparse` on the `substitute`, it returns a `character`

```
my_function <- function(arg1) substitute(arg1)
```

-testing

```
> my_function(x)
x
> my_function(y)
y
```